# Are there any version control systems out there that can be installed with XCOPY deployment?

Tags: version-control, deployment, xcopy

There are lots of version control systems out there. Git, Mercurial, SVN, TFS... But I think they all require installation. Are there any systems that can be installed just be copying the files?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you looked at [Fossil](http://www.fossil-scm.org/index.html/doc/trunk/www/index.wiki)?  It is a single stand-alone executable.

Answer (score 1):

[Portable Git](http://markashleybell.com/portable-git-windows-setting-home-environment-variable.html) comes to mind

> Portable Git is a completely
>   standalone version of the Git
>   distributed version control system.
>   All you need do to get going is to
>   download a file and unzip it into a
>   folder.